# Galaxy Tab Emulator for Android

Tags: android, emulation

How do you make an emulator for the galaxy tab that fits my project correctly.
here is a picture of what the layout looks like in the xml in eclipse...
http://s12.postimage.org/5xki5p43h/Correct_Tab.png and here is the layout when I run it in an emulator... http://postimage.org/image/iicfmxfpn/ . Do you have any Idea why it is like this I am running the traget as the "GALAXY TAB Addon - API Level 8" and I am using the built in skin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right emulator installed and using the right emulator(if you wanna 7 inch galaxy tab).
Just you need add a new folder drawable-xhdpi in res because the galaxy tab API Level 8 uses layout from drawable-xhdpi during the runtime. not from drawable-hdpi. Create a new folder add try.

Comment: I dont want the 7 inch though I want the 10.1 what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "GALAXY TAB Addon - API Level 8 is for 7inch tab run your app as API 11 it is 10 inch tab

Comment: Just one quick question, does it update automaticly when you edit the code in ecplice will it change in the emulator or do you just have to reopen the emulator each time?

Comment: no need of reopening of emulotor just build and run your roject